# How to put a vector in INDArray of ND4J?

Tags: java, tensor, nd4j

```
INDArray a = Nd4j.zeros(2,2);
a.put(1,Nd4j.create(nw float[]{1.0,2.0}));
```

I have tried above code but it give below error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Element must be a scalar
```

I am new to ND4J lib. Is there a way to directly put a vector?

```
 /**
     * Inserts the element at the specified index
     *
     * @param indices the indices to insert into
     * @param element a scalar ndarray
     * @return a scalar ndarray of the element at this index
     */
    INDArray put(int[] indices, INDArray element);
```

I can see above method in source code but for that I will need to create int array which will consume memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is `putRow`, which has the desired signature:

```
INDArray putRow(int row, INDArray toPut);
```

There is also `putColumn` that works similarly for columns.